# How to validate multiple strings exist, are not null, and not empty

Tags: javascript

Somewhat new to JS, and have a question. I have multiple strings that are being filled out in a form. I want to validate we have them all and they're not null or empty. Here's what I'm working with.

```
let valid = !!(this.state.str1 && this.state.str2 && this.state.str3
        && this.state.str4 && this.state.str5
        && this.state.str6);
```

valid keeps coming out 'undefined' when all have values.

Comment: `valid` should *never* be `undefined`, because the `!!` should cast to a Boolean. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: @CertainPerformance. Thanks for the feedback. I'm seeing it come back on debugger as 'undefined', which is odd. Not sure what else would satisfy the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable for ya. That's all the code really, besides these getting values, which would not be minimal. I've just set values on all these with test data and still 'undefined'

Comment: @CertainPerformance. LOL Had to edit. Sorry not here much so sent it without comments.

Comment: There's still just no possible way that the current code results in `valid` being `undefined` after that line runs. Again, without a [MCVE] that allows potential answerers to figure out what's going on, the question is unanswerable

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yep, I see it now. It must have been a debugger issue. I've ran it a couple times and it's evaluating as a bool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> valid keeps coming out 'undefined' when all have values.

Unfortunately, that's impossible, as even `!!undefined` is `false` and not `undefined`.

We know little about your code, but most likely guess would be that line of code isn't even being executed.